Find a set of permutations which minimises the maximum tree-distance between any 2 elements

I have an ordered sequence of $n=2^k$ elements, denoted $a_{1:n}=(a_1,...,a_n)$
The elements are organised in a balanced binary tree, so EG $a_1$ and $a_2$ share a parent, $a_1$ and $a_3$ share a grandparent (also shared by $a_2$ and $a_4$), etc
Define the distance $d(a_i, a_j)$ between elements as the difference in depth between the leaf nodes and their common ancestor, EG $d(a_1, a_1)=0,\quad d(a_1, a_2)=1,\quad d(a_1, a_4)=2,\quad d(a_1, a_{2^i})=i,\quad d(a_8, a_9)=d(a_1, a_9)=d(a_1, a_{16})=4,\quad d(a_9, a_{10})=1$
So in a sequence with $2^k$ elements (balanced binary tree with $2^k$ leaf nodes), the maximum distance between any 2 elements is $k$
Given $n=2^k$, define the distance matrix $D\in\mathbb{N}^{n\times n}$ as $D_{ij}=d(a_i, a_j)$
We can compute and visualise $D$ as follows:

import numpy as np
from jutility import plotting

def d(k: int) -> np.ndarray:
    n = 1 << k
    a_n11 = np.arange(n).reshape(n, 1, 1)
    p_11k = np.arange(k).reshape(1, 1, k)
    b_n1k = (a_n11 >> p_11k) & 1
    b_1nk = b_n1k.reshape(1, n, k)
    s_nnk = np.where(b_n1k == b_1nk, 0, 1 + p_11k)
    d_nn = s_nnk.max(axis=-1)
    return d_nn

k = 4
d_nn = d(k)
print(d_nn)
plotting.plot(plotting.ImShow(d_nn), figsize=[6, 6])



Now, consider a permuted sequence $\pi(a_{1:n})$ with elements denoted by $(a_{\pi(1)},...,a_{\pi(n)})$
Define the distance $d_\pi$ of any 2 elements in the permuted sequence as $d_\pi(a_i, a_j)=d(a_{\pi^{-1}(i)}, a_{\pi^{-1}(j)})$ and the permuted distance matrix with elements $D(\pi)_{ij}=d_\pi(a_i, a_j)=D_{\pi^{-1}(i),\pi^{-1}(j)}$ (see footnote explaining this definition)
We can compute and visualise $D(\pi)$ by permuting the rows and columns of $D$ using $\pi$, as shown below (red crosses correspond to pairs of elements which are siblings in the permuted sequence $\pi(a_{1:n})$ but not in the original sequence $a_{1:n}$):

...

def d_perm(n: int, d_nn: np.ndarray, pi_n: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    assert sorted(pi_n.tolist()) == list(range(n))
    pi_n1 = pi_n.reshape(n, 1)
    pi_1n = pi_n.reshape(1, n)
    dpi_nn = np.empty_like(d_nn)
    dpi_nn[pi_n1, pi_1n] = d_nn
    return dpi_nn

n = 1 << k
pi_n = np.arange(n)
pi_n[[1, 7, 12]] = [7, 12, 1]
dpi_nn = d_perm(n, d_nn, pi_n)

ticks  = {"xticks": [0, 6, 13], "yticks": [7, 12, 1]}
labels = {"xlabel": "i", "ylabel": "j"}
plotting.MultiPlot(
    plotting.Subplot(
        plotting.ImShow(d_nn, axis_off=False),
        plotting.Scatter([0, 6, 13], [1, 7, 12], c="r", m="x", s=15),
        **ticks,
        **labels,
        title="$d(i, j)$",
    ),
    plotting.Subplot(
        plotting.ImShow(dpi_nn, axis_off=False),
        plotting.Scatter([0, 6, 13], [7, 12, 1], c="r", m="x", s=15),
        **ticks,
        **labels,
        title="$d_\\pi(i, j)=d(\\pi^{-1}(i), \\pi^{-1}(j))$",
    ),
    title="$\\pi(0:15)$ = %s" % pi_n.tolist(),
    title_font_size=12,
    figsize=[6, 3],
).save()



Now, the problem I want to solve is to find a set of permutations such that every pair of elements in $a_{1:n}$ is close together in at least one permutation (obviously not all pairs of elements can be close together all permutations)
Define $\pi_{1:m}$ as a set of $m$ permutations with elements $(\pi_1,...,\pi_m)$
Define the distance matrix $D(\pi_{1:m})$ for the set $\pi_{1:m}$ with elements $D(\pi_{1:m})_{ij}=\min_{k\in\{1,...,m\}}[D(\pi_k)_{ij}]$
Given a few permutations, we can compute and visualise $D(\pi_{1:m})$ as follows:

...

def d_perm_set(n: int, d_nn: np.ndarray, *pi_n: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    dpi_mnn = np.stack([d_perm(n, d_nn, pi) for pi in pi_n], axis=-3)
    dpi_nn = dpi_mnn.min(axis=-3)
    return dpi_nn

def plot_d(k: int, d_nn: np.ndarray) -> plotting.Subplot:
    return plotting.Subplot(plotting.ImShow(d_nn, vmin=0, vmax=k))

def plot_perm_set(k: int, d_nn: np.ndarray, *pi_n: np.ndarray) -> plotting.MultiPlot:
    n = 1 << k
    ds_nn = d_perm_set(n, d_nn, *pi_n)
    return plotting.MultiPlot(
        plotting.MultiPlot(
            *[plot_d(k, d_perm(n, d_nn, pi)) for pi in pi_n],
            title="$\\{D(\\pi_i)\\}_{i=1}^m$",
        ),
        plotting.MultiPlot(
            plot_d(k, ds_nn),
            title="$D(\\pi_{1:m})$",
        ),
        figsize=[10, 5],
        space=0.2,
    )

a_n = np.arange(n)

pi2 = np.empty_like(pi_n)
pi2[0::2] = np.arange(n >> 1)
pi2[1::2] = np.arange(n >> 1) + (n >> 1)

pi3 = np.empty_like(pi_n)
pi3[0::2] = np.arange(n >> 1)
pi3[1::2] = n - 1 - np.arange(n >> 1)

pi_list = [a_n, pi_n, pi2, pi3, pi3[pi3], pi3[pi3[pi3]]]
plot_perm_set(k, d_nn, *pi_list).save()



Intuitively, $D(\pi_{1:m})_{ij}$ is small if $(a_i,a_j)$ are close together in at least one permutation
We want to find $\pi_{1:m}$ such that every pair $(a_i,a_j)$ is close together in at least one permutation, so define the cost $C(\pi_{1:m})$ for the set $\pi_{1:m}$ as $C(\pi_{1:m})=\max_{i,j\in\{1,...,n\}}[D(\pi_{1:m})_{ij}]=\max_{i,j\in\{1,...,n\}}[\min_{k\in\{1,...,m\}}[D(\pi_k)_{ij}]]$
The problem (at last) is to find a method to compute the smallest set $\pi_{1:m}$ that minimises the cost $C(\pi_{1:m})$


Footnote:

Why define $D(\pi)_{ij}=D_{\pi^{-1}(i),\pi^{-1}(j)}$ and not $D(\pi)_{ij}=D_{\pi(i),\pi(j)}$?
Intuitively, if $a_i$ and $a_j$ are siblings in $a_{1:n}$ then $D_{ij}$ is small, which occurs when $\pi(a_i)$ and $\pi(a_j)$ are siblings in $\pi(a_{1:n})$ and $D(\pi)_{\pi(i),\pi(j)}$ is small
Similarly, if $a_i$ and $a_j$ are siblings in $\pi(a_{1:n})$ then $D(\pi)_{ij}$ is small, which occurs when $\pi^{-1}(a_i)$ and $\pi^{-1}(a_j)$ are siblings in $a_{1:n}$ and $D_{\pi^{-1}(i),\pi^{-1}(j)}$ is small
In summary, $D(\pi)_{ij}=D_{\pi^{-1}(i),\pi^{-1}(j)}$ is small when $a_i$ and $a_j$ are close together in $\pi(a_{1:n})$
So if we want to choose $\pi$ to make $D(\pi)_{ij}$ small, we just put $a_i$ and $a_j$ close together in $\pi(a_{1:n})$


Below is a solution which, given $n=2^k$, finds a set of $n-1$ permutations for which every pair of elements are siblings in exactly one permutation (followed by some visualisations):
...

def best_perm_set(k: int) -> np.ndarray:
    n = 1 << k
    a_n = np.arange(n)
    pi_mn = np.zeros([n-1, n], dtype=int)
    pi_mn[0, 1] = 1
    for s in range(1, k):
        t = 1 << s
        t2 = t << 1
        tm1 = t - 1
        t2m1 = t2 - 1
        pi_mn[:tm1, t:t2] = pi_mn[:tm1, :t] + t

        a_t = a_n[:t]
        a_1t = a_t.reshape(1, t)
        a_t1 = a_t.reshape(t, 1)
        pi_mn[tm1:t2m1, 0:t2:2] = a_1t
        pi_mn[tm1:t2m1, 1:t2:2] = ((a_1t + a_t1) % t) + t

    return pi_mn

plotting.MultiPlot(
    plotting.Subplot(plotting.ImShow(best_perm_set(4)), title="k=%i" % 4),
    plotting.Subplot(plotting.ImShow(best_perm_set(6)), title="k=%i" % 6),
    plotting.Subplot(plotting.ImShow(best_perm_set(8)), title="k=%i" % 8),
    figsize=[9, 3],
    num_rows=1,
).save("im1")

k = 4
n = 1 << k
d_nn = d(k)
pi_mn = best_perm_set(k)
pi_list = np.split(pi_mn, n-1, axis=0)
pi_list = [pi_n.reshape(n) for pi_n in pi_list]
plot_perm_set(k, d_nn, *pi_list).save("im2")

pi_mn = best_perm_set(10)
plotting.MultiPlot(
    plotting.Subplot(plotting.ImShow(pi_mn[:, 1::2])),
    plotting.Subplot(plotting.ImShow(pi_mn[:, 0::2])),
    figsize=[10, 10],
    pad=0,
).save("im3")






[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
 [ 0  2  1  3  4  6  5  7  8 10  9 11 12 14 13 15]
 [ 0  3  1  2  4  7  5  6  8 11  9 10 12 15 13 14]
 [ 0  4  1  5  2  6  3  7  8 12  9 13 10 14 11 15]
 [ 0  5  1  6  2  7  3  4  8 13  9 14 10 15 11 12]
 [ 0  6  1  7  2  4  3  5  8 14  9 15 10 12 11 13]
 [ 0  7  1  4  2  5  3  6  8 15  9 12 10 13 11 14]
 [ 0  8  1  9  2 10  3 11  4 12  5 13  6 14  7 15]
 [ 0  9  1 10  2 11  3 12  4 13  5 14  6 15  7  8]
 [ 0 10  1 11  2 12  3 13  4 14  5 15  6  8  7  9]
 [ 0 11  1 12  2 13  3 14  4 15  5  8  6  9  7 10]
 [ 0 12  1 13  2 14  3 15  4  8  5  9  6 10  7 11]
 [ 0 13  1 14  2 15  3  8  4  9  5 10  6 11  7 12]
 [ 0 14  1 15  2  8  3  9  4 10  5 11  6 12  7 13]
 [ 0 15  1  8  2  9  3 10  4 11  5 12  6 13  7 14]]

